# Exclude own visits from being reported on Blogger stats

Tags: blogger, statistics

[Blogger real-time stats](http://buzz.blogger.com/2010/08/introducing-blogger-stats.html) was introduced. How can I exclude my own visits from counting in these statistics?

I know it is possible to set a cookie to [exclude self traffic in Google Analytics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?rd=1). Is something similar possible with Blogger real-time stats?

Comment: dont visit :P ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Sweet! Blogger in Draft just implemented a feature to exclude your own visits.** It does not seam to work, yet, though.

**Update:** This cookie does not seem to hold it's value and work in IE (8). I realize it is just a "draft" feature, but I'm considering [using the HOSTS file](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/blogger-stats-how-to-exclude-own-visits/6210#6210) instead.

**Update 2:** Even when the cookie maintains it's value in non-IE browsers, the visits are still tracked. This new "draft" feature still has some kinks...

There is a new "Don't track your own pageviews" link in the real-time stats tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Block the Google Analytics domain from your HOSTS file:

```
# [Google Inc]
127.0.0.1 www.google-analytics.com
127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com
```

Apparently this might break some sites...

sources:

- [Prevent Google Analytics from tracking your visit](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2005/11/prevent-google-analytics-from-tracking.html)
- [how to make the internet not suck (as much)](http://someonewhocares.org/hosts/)

**update:** Blogger doesn't seem to use these URL's... anyone know the right URL to block?

Answer (score 0):

I have been playing around with the Blogger stats and the "Don't track your own pageviews" option. Using an obscure blog of mine which gets 0 traffic, I noticed that every refresh resulted in a +1 in the stats page.
After many experiments and fiddling around, I noticed that my blog redirects to a country-specific url (.co.il, in my case). I tried navigating to the .com url (Using the /ncr option, as specified [here](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/2402711?hl=en)), and finally got it to work - refreshing the .co.il tab adds 1 to my stats, refreshing the .com tab does not.
Seems like a bug on Google's side. I hope they will get it fixed.